# C# How to create TabPage as child form of MDI?

Tags: c#

I would like to create TabPages (fill docked with frmCalculationReport) as child forms of a MDI, so that I can switch active TabPage from ToolStripMenu such as "Window" pull down menu.

I have one tabControl1 fill docked in MDI MainWindow with ToolStripMenu of that "Window".

When I click one ToolStripMenu item such as performCodeCalculationsToolStripMenuItem from MDI MainWindow, I would like one TabPage (with a docked frmCalculationReport) added on tabControl1 as a child form of MDI MainWindow. Following are the codes. But, I do not know how to add the TabPages as child of MDI MainWindows. Any suggestion and comments will be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void performCodeCalculationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = "CalReport";
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

        CalculationReport frmCalculationReport = new CalculationReport();
        frmCalculationReport.TopLevel = false;
        frmCalculationReport.Visible = true;
        frmCalculationReport.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frmCalculationReport.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabCount - 1].Controls.Add(frmCalculationReport);
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabControl1.TabCount - 1;
    }
```

Comment: The tab page should be added to the tab control.

Comment: It is added. see tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

Comment: Usa a Panel which you can then add to a tabPage or to a new child form etc..! TabPages can only reside in Tab controls.